# how does Sencha Touch delta update mechanism work?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I can see while testing with Chrome on my laptop, that Sencha Touch saved app.js/app.json/app.css in LocalStorage. When I upload some new code to web server, Sencha Touch APP will check it automatically and prompt to inform user to upgrade. Anyone know how this auto delta upgrade works under the hood?

Comment: Every class and every function is a javascript object, and when you replace it with another object going by the same name, the old function is overwritten with the new one. `Ext.apply` takes two Javascript objects and replaces all objects that are in the first with those in the second, if available. The first is the old program version, and the second is the delta, which is read from a smaller "delta" file. If this is not what you want to know, please elaborate on what you mean by "under the hood"...

Comment: I mean when and how these files app.js/app.json/app.css, which are cached in client, will be updated. Will Sencha check the delta folder to look for delta files (there are many of them) to determine if an upgrade is needed? if there are many delta files, which one or ones will be picked up?

Comment: The delta file name is standardized and includes the ID of the old version and the ID of the new version. The newest ID is stored in the .appcache file, the old ID is stored in the local storage. If they differ, the file name of the delta is built using both of them and the single delta file that contains all differences between the two versions is requested. If it can't be found, the complete file is downloaded.

Comment: Btw. I would recommend to read .sencha/app/microloader/production.js in your Touch project directory. That should make it clear what happens under the hood. :)